# Do Java and C represent a UTF char byte in the same way?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, utf

I'm passing an array of bytes from Java to C, I think Java and C represent UTF char bytes the same way.

Can I just do this:

```
jbyte *bytePtr = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, javaByteArray, NULL);

// javaByteArray has java bytes for the UTF chars: 'A', 'B', 'C'

unsigned char *bytePtrC = (unsigned char *) bytePtr;

printf("%c %c %c \n", bytePtrC, bytePtrC+1, bytePtrC+2);

// will this print A B C ?
```

Comment: Afaik no, C uses Ascii (8-Bit), while Java uses UTF-16 (16-Bit)

Comment: @hellow C doesn't certainly "use Ascii (8-Bit)".

Comment: @hellow: The C standard does not require ASCII. Many C implementations use ASCII, but there are alternatives. And C is not limited to eight-bit characters. In addition to the fact that `char` is not limited to eight bits by the C standard, C also supports wide characters in its `wchar_t` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

*Binary* byte arrays presenting data like two shorts would be identical.

*Text* is another matter. Java had by design **text** (String, char) in Unicode, and `char` is a two byte UTF-16 value. There always is a conversion from `byte[]` to `String` with some encoding of those bytes to be used.

So one has in java:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This would almost be a C array, but for these differences:

- bytes.length as field
- C has an extra terminating nul char: `'\0'`
- the java String could contain a nul char; some classes ([DataOutputStream.writeUTF8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)))
  will encode it too in a multi-byte sequence for interoperability with C strings.
  This is called *modified UTF-8*.

But there is no real problem. Only ensure:

- Use `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of `String.getBytes()`.
- Use `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of `new String(bytes)`.
- Never ever use String and char for binary data, as one would use C `unsigned char*`. It would use twice the memory, a slow conversion back and forth that may corrupt the data.
- Concerning binary data (`ByteBuffer.order`): short, int, long and such are big-endian in java.

As the latter versions use the default encoding of the platform, which is not portable.

Comment: Thanks, the javaByteArray is from a java string using .getBytes(UTF8) so I should be ok.

Comment: Yes; in fact me crying out **No** is quite relative; there are just a couple of things to consider - that were listed.

Comment: It all worked. You are wise and have the wisdom of the ancients.